# Selenium Web Scraping IE when show promt for download

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to web scraping and download files using python, selenium and Internet explorer.
But this show me a promp with confirmation, How to confirm to save automatically or programtically?.

```
boton_download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a[1]/img[1]")
boton_donwload.click()
```

*Do you want to open or save Reporrrr.MND from [www.asdasd.com](http://www.asdasd.com)? Open  Save  Cancel*

[image]